Is it possible to get items from previous expeditions on No Man's Sky?
I started playing the game a little over a year ago and noticed the previously available expeditions. While some of the items I can get by without, some ships and customizations would be nice to have.
I was watching a YouTube video about the game and the creator mentioned that all the expeditions come back every year. Looking through the comments, someone asked about previous expeditions and the YouTuber replied,

they put all expeditions again from Oct to New year until new major update arrives

I don't remember seeing this last year. Is this true? Is it possible to get items from previous expeditions this way?

It's somewhat true, abbreviated versions of Expeditions from the current year are usually repeated between the end of November and beginning of January. You can see the official announcements from Hello Games for 2021, 2022, 2023. Expeditions from the years before (prior to Expedition 12 in 2024) are currently not expected to return.
If you're playing on PC, you might have success with this guide though.

For whatever reason, I didn't understand your answer at first (probably too tired). After reading the links you provided and re-reading your answer makes sense now. BTW, It would probably be helpful for other readers if you added the links to your answer.
